# Doubly linked list std::unique_ptr template class implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++14, template, pointers

Inspired by [the talk of Herb Sutter in CppCon2016](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE?t=1467), I decided to make a doubly linked list using templates, smart pointers, and raw pointers (for back-pointers, having a cycle of `std::unique_ptr`s would be a bug).

The following proof-of-concept implementation compiles and works properly.
I would love to hear your suggestions / improvements about the entire header and your design approach.

Below you can find the header and a small test main.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace DLL {
    template <typename T> class LinkedList{
        private:
            struct ListNode{
                std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next; //2 uniq_ptr can't point to one another.
                ListNode* prev = nullptr; //weakptr needs to be cast back to a shared_ptr to check its state.
                T data{}; //Initialize empty;

            ListNode(const T& element){
                this->data = element;
            }
        };
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<ListNode> head;
        ListNode* tail = nullptr;

        LinkedList(){}
        ~LinkedList(){}

        void append(const T& element){
            ListNode* curr = nullptr;
            if (head.get() == nullptr){ //If list is empty.
                head = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
            }
            else if(head.get() -> next.get() == nullptr){ //If list has one element.
                 head.get() -> next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
                 curr = head.get() -> next.get(); //Sets raw pointer to the first element.
                 curr -> prev = head.get();
                 tail = curr;
            }
            else{
                tail -> next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(element);
                curr = tail -> next.get(); //Sets raw pointer to the last element.
                curr -> prev = tail;
                tail = curr;// The new last element is the tail.
            }
        }

        int remove(const T& element){ 
            ListNode* curr = nullptr;
            if (head.get() == nullptr){ //If list is empty.
                return -1; //Error: Can't remove from empty list.
            }
            //List has one or more elements.
            curr = head.get();
            while(curr != nullptr){
                if(curr -> data == element){ //Found element.
                    if(curr -> prev == nullptr){ //it's head
                        head = std::move(curr -> next); //Head now points to the next element.
                        if (head) {
                            head->prev = nullptr;
                        }
                    //New head's previous element points to nothing, making it a true head element.
                    }
                    else if(curr -> next.get() == nullptr){ //it's tail.
                        tail = curr -> prev; //Reference the previous element.
                        tail -> next.reset(); //Destroy the old tail element.
                        if(head.get() == tail){
                            tail = nullptr; //tail and head should not be the same.
                        } //List contains one element.
                    }
                    else{//it's intermediate.
                        //The next node should point to the previous one
                        curr -> next -> prev = curr -> prev;
                        curr -> prev -> next = std::move(curr -> next);
                        //The prev node now points to the next one of current.
                    }
                    return 1; //Element found in list.
                }
                curr = curr -> next.get(); //Traverse the next element.
            }
            return 0; //Element not found in list.
        }

        void print() {
            ListNode* curr = head.get(); //Start from the start of the list.
            std::cout << "[ ";
            while (curr != nullptr) {
                std::cout << curr -> data << " ";
                curr = curr -> next.get();
            }
            std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() { //Temporary Test Main will be split from the implementation file in the future
    DLL::LinkedList <int> list; //Create an empty list

    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.append(4);
    list.append(5);
    list.print();

    list.remove(5);
    list.print();
    list.remove(1);
    list.print();
    list.remove(3);
    list.print();
    list.remove(2);
    list.print();
    list.remove(4);
    list.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with g++: `g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o out` and with the `VS2015` compiler.
The C++14 flag is needed for the `std::make_unique` call.

Comment: you'll want to ask a follow up question to make sure you're not invalidating any answers that have been posted already.

Comment: @Vogel612: At that time there were no answers to be invalidated (yet). And even the one that exists by now didn't mention the corrected issue.

Comment: @hitter: For the future, you might want to wait a bit (e.g. 24 hours) before accepting an answer, as it takes some time to write a good review and an already accepted answer discourages others who might write a better one ;)

Comment: Seems the part finally killing this idea might be the Iterator-Invalidation-rules.

Comment: @Deduplicator The idea is fully implemented now with more methods and most of hoffmale recommendations.
It's not production-ready (never I attempted it to be), it was just a little expirement for me to practice some of smart pointer, template stuff I learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Implementation issues

- There's no way to store a move-only type (or rather any non-copyable type) in the `LinkedList` (e.g. this means you cannot have a `DLL::LinkedList<std::unique_ptr<int>>`). Maybe provide overloads that accept a `T&&`, and/or add an `emplace` member function that constructs a `T` in place?
- Prefer using a member initializer list over assigning inside the constructor body. This allows `ListNode::data` to be copy-constructed directly, instead of being default-constructed and then copy-assigned. Also, it might provide better optimization opportunities and better exception guarantees (if something inside the constructor throws, already constructed members get properly destructed).
- `ListNode`s constructor(s) can be marked conditionally `noexcept`.
- Also, it might be more convenient to allow setting the `next` and `prev` pointers of a `ListNode` directly inside the `ListNode` constructor(s) (see later for an example).

> An `ListNode` implementation supporting all above mentioned points might look something like this:
>
> ```
> struct ListNode {
>     std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next;
>     ListNode* prev;
>     T data;
>
>     ListNode(std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next, ListNode* prev, const T& element) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
>         : next{std::move(next)}, prev{prev}, data{element} {}
>
>     ListNode(std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next, ListNode* prev, T&& elemente) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
>         : next{std::move(next)}, prev{prev}, data{std::move(element) {}
>
>     template<typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>>
>     ListNode(std::unique_ptr<ListNode> next, ListNode* prev, Args&&... args) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>)
>         : next{std::move(next)}, prev{prev}, data{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
> };
> ```

- `LinkedList`s default constructor could be `= default`, as no actual work is done.
- `~LinkedList() {}` is problematic: Yes, it does clean up memory, but only until it hits the call stack limits due to recursion. Just try letting a `LinkedList` with a million (or so) elements destruct (e.g. by letting it fall out of scope).

  > You might want to rewatch minutes 16:00 to around 26:00 in the video, Herb Sutter explains this problem far better than I could in this limited space.
  >
  > Since an iterative destructor implementation was requested:
  >
  > ```
  > ~LinkedList() noexcept {
  >     while(head) head = std::move(head->next);
  > }
  > ```
- Rule of Five violation: A custom destructor is provided, but no copy-constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator.

  > Move assignment and move construction are pretty easy to implement (actually, they can be `= default`).
  >
  > However, copy assignment and copy construction aren't quite as easy: They require `T` to be copy-constructible. If copying a `LinkedList` isn't important, you could `= delete` those two special functions.
- `LinkedList::append(const T&)` issues

  - A lot of the calls to `std::unique_ptr::get` are unnecessary. The only necessary ones are `curr = head->next.get();`, `curr->prev = head.get();` and `curr = tail->next.get()`;
  - The whole `else if` branch could be remove if `tail` would be allowed to point to the same node as `head` (in a `LinkedList` of size 1).
  - The whole pointer moving business can be simplified using the constructors of `ListNode` above that take those pointer values.
  - The `const T&` parameter only works if `T` itself is copy constructible. This can be checked using type traits, and the function be made unavailable (using SFINAE) if copy-construction is not supported by `T`.

  > A simplified and cleaned up version could look something like this:
  >
  > ```
  > std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value> append(const T& element) {
  >     if(!head) {
  >         head = std::make_unique<ListNode>(nullptr, nullptr, element);
  >         tail = head.get();
  >     } else {
  >         tail->next = std::make_unique<ListNode>(nullptr, tail, element);
  >         tail = tail->next.get();
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
- `LinkedList::remove(const T&)` issues:

  - Is there a specific reason that removing a value from an empty `LinkedList` returns a different result than removing a non-existent value form a non-empty `LinkedList`?
  - Speaking about return values: Is it necessary to return one at all?
  - The whole logic of `remove` could be split into two helper functions: 1) Finding the nodes whose value matches and 2) removing a specific node.

    > Finding a node (or removing a specific node) are operations that will likely be reused in the future anyways, so this will likely help implementing additional features.
  - Again, like in `append`, some of the removal logic could be simplified if `tail` were allowed to point to the same node as `head`.

  > Example fixup:
  >
  > ```
  > private:
  >     ListNode* find_node(const T& value, ListNode* current) const {
  >         while(current) {
  >             if(current->data == value) return current;
  >             current = current->next.get();
  >         }
  >         return nullptr;
  >     }
  >
  >     void remove_node(ListNode* node) {
  >         if(node->next) {
  >             node->next->prev = node->prev;
  >         } else {
  >             tail = node->prev;
  >         }
  >
  >         // the assignments below reset the original owner, thus node will be dangling afterwards!
  >         if(node->prev) {
  >             node->prev->next = std::move(node->next);
  >         } else {
  >             head = std::move(node->next);
  >         }
  >     }
  >
  > public:
  >     void remove(const T& value) {
  >         for(auto node = find_node(head.get()); node; node = find_node(value, node)) {
  >             auto temp = node;
  >             node = node->next.get();
  >             remove_node(temp);
  >         }
  >     }
  > ```
  >
  > Much more readable, and easier to reason about, isn't it?
- `LinkedList::print`: While this function might be nice for debugging, it doesn't seem to be in the general scope of the `LinkedList` class: If there is any way of iteration over the nodes, the `print` function can easily be implemented outside of `LinkedList` (if/where needed).

  If there really is a need for `LinkedList` to support text output, try to implement `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const DLL::LinkedList&)` instead.

## Naming

The common C++ standard library naming conventions would suggest `push_back` instead of `append`.

## Design

A lot of common linked list operations are missing:

- `push_front`
- `emplace_back`
- `emplace_front`
- `insert` (*)
- `emplace` (*)
- `erase` (*)
- `find` (*)
- Iterators

(*) These functions might be easier to implement (without leaking `ListNode*`s) or perform better if using iterators.

Comment: 1. You know the templated ctor for `ListNode` makes both non-templated ones you added superfluous? 2. Anyway, removing them all would allow for Aggregate-initialization. No need for the boilerplate. 3. It Looks like a POC, so probably only a small part of the interface exists yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Correct on all counts. Re #3: I mostly provided those design hints in case this gets expanded further.

Comment: @hitter: Just did.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Wait a sec, Re #2: That would prevent you from using `std::make_unique`, which the templated constructor still allows.

Comment: Hm, why? Anyway, how bout those iterators?

Comment: @Deduplicator: [iterator implementation](https://pastebin.com/fPh12m81) Just the iterator though (`const_iterator` would be similar).

Comment: @hoffmale: If I see it right, it depends on pinning down an additional node and some fancier dancing. `std::list`'s iterators only have license to pin down the node they point to (an end-iterator not pointing to any), and that's what they do.

Comment: @Deduplicator: You can easily replace `ListNode* last` with a `LinkedList* list`, changing `void next() { current = current->next.get(); }` and `void prev() { if(current) current = current->prev; else current = list->tail; }`. That way you only "pin" one node, but lose the ability to have an "before the head" iterator. (and adjusting `operator==`, ofc)

Comment: So, how does thereafter a begin-iterator look, and how an end-Iterator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80814/discussion-between-hoffmale-and-deduplicator).

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a reason I wouldn't ever use a smart-pointer which isn't a shared-pointer or self-relative as base for a doubly-linked-list:

Most of the time, one has to work around the smart-pointer to get things done efficiently, or with the right semantics at all. Some examples from your code:

1. Your list-destructor is deeply recursive, needing \$O(n)\$ stack-space. An iterative version would only need a miniscule fixed amount of stack-space and be faster too. That *can* be fixed without going to different pointers, but you are fighting against them.
2. You must handle an empty list, specifically inserting or removing the first node, as a special case. Special-casing leads to repetition and loss of efficiency.
3. You will have difficulties creating a standard iterator-interface for your list: Iterators to nodes are fine, but what about the end-iterator? [The container-requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#9) say that all iterators to elements have to stay valid after container-swap (`std::array` obviously has an exception).

Base your list-class and its nodes on something like the following instead, and do your memory-management manually or with shared-pointers when building that basic abstraction.

```
struct node_base {
    node_base *next, *prev;
};
template <class T>
class linked_list {
    struct node { node_base links; T data; };
    node_base links { &links, &links };
    void fix_links() noexcept {
        if (links.next != links.prev)
            links.next->prev = links.prev->next = &links;
        else
            links.next = links.prev = &links;
    }
public:
    linked_list() = default;
    ~linked_list() {
        while (auto p = links.next; p != &links)
            delete (node*)std::exchange(p, p->next);
    }
...
```

Printing the list should be done by a free non-friend function using the now easily implemented iterator-interface. And it should probably be done in `template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, linked_list<T> const& ll)`.

Naturally, your proof-of-concept still misses most of its interface. Still, those you have should all follow the standard-library as closely as reasonable, in order to take advantage of all the template-magic and to follow the rule of least surprise.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has a lot of overhead that isn't needed for a simple doubly linked list. The only exception I could see if there is a special requirement for iterators to remain valid even when the lifetime of the linked list already ended (which is very rare IME). Also, creating an bidirectional iterator over a doubly linked list is nearly trivial.

Comment: @hoffmale Indubitably using shared_ptr's would be rare, but they are one of the two types of smart-pointers relevant at all. Regarding the iterators, I would love seeing you demonstrate ones as good as `std::list` for the OPs definitions.